# Layouts in desktop application

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am developing one java desktop application with a lots of panels with different and same layouts. Now when I want to set to panel new layout I always create new layout. E.G.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
```

Is the correct solution to create some `LayoutFactory` and here create all the layouts that I need and then set to the panels?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: no need for a factory (some can't even be shared)

Comment: and what about layout which can be shared ? E.G When I search in my project for flowLayout I found that I am creating about 30 instances of this layout

Comment: Are those 30 tiny objects (and layoutmanagers are tiny) a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) laying JPanel by new `GridLayout(0, 1)` should be same as `BorderLayout.CENTER` or possible by using `BoxLayout`, in this case you place only one `JComponent` for whole `JPanel`

2) easiest way is lay `JComponents` by `Nested Layout` where each of Container can have different [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), same `LayoutManager` or their combinations

3) by using [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) or [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) is possible (in most of cases) place every `JComponents` once time for whole container or `JPanel`

Comment: #1 `GridLayout(0,1)` is different from `BorderLayout.CENTER`. It defines a layout with one column and as many equal rows as elements are added.   Even a `GridLayout(1,1)` doesn't have only one cell when more elements are added, it adds columns dynamically. `BoxLayout` has different effects, it doesn't resize components. #3 JGoodies FormLayout is a good alternative for this purpose also.

Answer (score 0):

hudi, if you want to make your code more concise, you can write helper methods which create and assign the layouts. If you are setting up layouts in only one class, the helper methods can be `private` methods of that class. Or if you are setting up layouts in various classes, you may be able to add `protected` helper methods to a common superclass (if you have one), or as `static` methods on a utility class.

Post the details of your code and we can give more specific suggestions.